# Liferay portal: UTF-8 encoding

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have troubles with liferay portal encoding. Special (UTF8) chars like ščšć are not displayed properly (all of them are displayed like �)

Header looks fine:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
```

Im upgrading liferay from 6.0.5 to 6.1.2. With 6.0.5 everything worked fine.
First I thought that language.properties file could be the problem, but the text from portlets is corrupted as well.

Im using weblogic webserver 10.3.4.

EDIT: 
Non translated static text from portlets is displayed properly.

But translated text in potlets (using liferay-ui:message tag) is corrupted.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding can go wrong on many different levels: The database should use UTF-8, the driver be configured to use this encoding as well. The appserver's (and Java's) default encoding also might play into it. And then the webserver/appserver connection and proxies can play into it.

As the previous version worked, start to check the database and what the database driver uses (e.g. the driver's URL). Be prepared to use a backup. Recovering from a database that contains a mix of encodings would be really hard.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I think its not database problem. Non translated static text from portlets is displayed properly. Translated text in potlets - using <liferay-ui:message key="message-key" /> tag is corrupted - means that liferay doesn't read language files correctly....and yes, files are in UTF-8 encodnig.

Comment: It could be appserver's and Java's default encoding, but why then 6.0.5 works without any problem? (Ofc. I also checked all settings, they are correct.)

Comment: Are you running 6.1.2 on *exactly* the same appserver as 6.0.5? On the same server, same configuration *in all aspects*? If not: Can you try this?

Comment: yes...Its all the same. I just changed liferay portal .war file to newer version and changed dependency files. Thats all. All other changes were made by liferay upgrade process.

Comment: I solved the problem. It's app server setting. Must be UTF-8 in 6.1.2, in 6.0.5 i had ISO-8859-2.  I already checked that setting, but it seems I was reading a wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing JVM setting.
In weblogics file setDomainEnv.cmd I changed Dfile.encoding.
With liferay 6.0.5 I was using:

```
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-2
```

Liferay 6.1.2 requires:

```
set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is in `portal-ext.properties` add `file.encoding=UTF-8`. This solved problem for me

Comment: I would guess you mean system-ext.properties.